# Jquery Ajax & PHP unlink

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am having a struggle with using jQuery to run an AJAX request which deletes files:

```
function deleteuploadedfile(filetodelete) {
             $imagefile = 'http://domain.co.uk/directory/uploads/'+filetodelete;
             alert($imagefile);
              $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                data: {
                    action: 'deleteimage',
                    imagefile: $imagefile,
                     },
            url: 'http://domain.co.uk/directory/delete.php',
            success: function(){
                alert('success');
              }
            })
        }


THE PHP FILE

<?php
    if($_POST["action"]=="deleteimage")
    {
        $imagefile = $_POST['imagefile'];
        $imagefileend = '/uploads/'.end(explode('images',$imagefile)); 
        unlink($_POST['imagefile']);
    }
?>
```

I am getting the alert 'success' But the files are not being removed from the server.

I have got this far, just need some guidance on what is happening and why the files are not being deleted.

Comment: This sounds distinctly like a permissions issue.  Which user owns the files?  [`chmod`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chmod) [`chown`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chown)

Comment: It's apache:apache I did think this..but thought as the files are uploaded via a php script this would be OK. I have also tried the directory as 777

Comment: Ah, never mind then - you seem to have a promising answer below anyway :)

Comment: Not appropriate to host your code on pastebin. Code needs to be included in the question, or not at all. You can use a 3rd party service like pastebin or jsfiddle to *supplement* your question, but you question can not rely on these services for its only content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your PHP code, you are doing:

```
unlink($_POST['imagefile']);
```

$_POST['imagefile'] is coming from your ajax call, and being set in javascript to:

```
$imagefile = 'http://domain.co.uk/directory/uploads/'+filetodelete;
$.ajax({type: 'POST',
        data: {
              action: 'deleteimage',
              imagefile: $imagefile,
        }
```

How do you expect PHP to be able to delete a remote URL?

You seem to be setting up a $imagefileend variable with a local path, but you aren't using it in your unlink() call. Double check what you are trying to unlink(), spit out the full path right before you try to unlink it, and verify it exists locally and that you have appropriate permissions.

Also, unlink() returns true or false, based on success. Capture that and use it to help debug.

**Suggested edit (untested):**

```
 if($_POST["action"]=="deleteimage")
 {
     $imagefile = basename($_POST['imagefile']); // See http://php.net/basename
     $path = '/uploads/'. $imagefile;
     if(!file_exists($path)) {
          echo json_encode(array("success" => 0, "error" => "File $imagefile does not exist"));
          exit;
     }

     if(!unlink($path)) {
          echo json_encode(array("success" => 0, "error" => "File could not be deleted, check permissions"));
          exit;  
     }

     echo json_encode(array("success" => 1));   
 }
```

Then have a callback in your ajax function client side, check for the server response, and ensure that success = 1.

```
success: function(data){
    var response = $.parseJSON(data);
    if(!response.success) {
        alert(response.error);
    } else {
        alert("success!");
    }
}
```

Also, I'd recommend using Chrome (or Firefox) and watching the Network tab of Developer Tools so you can see exactly what the server is returning from the ajax call.

Comment: Really appreciate your help and time. Just not too sure how I can put a callback in my ajax.

Comment: I updated the answer. You already have a success callback, use that. Just realize that the success callback only means that the ajax call was successful, not that the server action was necessarily successful. The JSON that the server is sending back will be available in the 'response' object, which you can inspect.

Comment: Many thanks for this. I understand the old callback was successful as the ajax call had completed. Using the above, I am getting an alert that states 'undefined'. I suppose this tells us there is an error. But not sure what the error is.

Comment: I am using the above for the delete.php script. However, I have changed the jquery so updated my most recent here: http://pastebin.com/PSFkSPrC

Comment: Ah yes, the callback gets plain text, not an object. I added $.parseJSON above, now you should have an object to inspect. Also, I'd recommend using Chrome (or Firefox) and watching the Network tab of Developer Tools so you can see exactly what the server is returning, just in case that's broken somehow.

Comment: AH! Feels like I am getting there - Thank you. It says file not found. So I have an idea where to look for the error now.

Comment: Works a treat! I had to delete the first slash on uploads and it worked perfectly. Thank you very much for your help! Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since the *PHP* script itself is located and the request is carried out ok you will get *success*. What you would have to do to let your *java script* code know that something went wrong in your *PHP* script is to return some kind of error code for your *java script* to read and act upon.

Regarding you *PHP* script you try to *unlink* **$_POST['imagefile']** which is a URL. This will not work so well. You should pass the **local path on the webserver** to the file you wish to delete.

Then return some code to your java script front end which indicates success or failure to delete the file and notify the user of that.